# Laravel 5.1 Model Delete Event

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5.1

I have a load of Models. Users can comment on some of the model records. For example, a user can comment on a Notice model record, or a user can comment on a Calendar Model record.

I've created a `trait` called `Commentable`. This contains all the methods needed to retrieve comments based on a model, to add / delete comments, create the comment create form and so on.

Whenever I want a model to be commentable, all I need to do is use that trait within the model.

Because that comment is a polymorphic relationship with the model record, I can't do an `onCascade = delete` migration.

Whenever the parent model is deleted (such as a notice or calendar item), then I want all associated records to be deleted as well, but I'd prefer not to have to rely on the developer writing the `deleteRelatedComments()` method call into an overridden delete function.

I thought I would create a service provider that listened for any model deletion event, check to see if that model was commentable, and delete any associated comments, but the event doesn't fire correctly.

This is my service provider code:

```
Model::deleting(function (Model $record) {
    if(in_array('App\Libraries\Traits\Commentable', class_uses($record))) {
        $record->deleteRelatedComments();
    }

    return true;
});
```

As you can see, all it does is check the deleted model to see if it uses the `Commentable` trait. If it does, it calls the `deleteRelatedComments()` method.

**My Question**

Is there any way to automatically delete related polymorphic related content on the deletion of it's parent record:

If I delete a `Notice` record, is there any way to delete any associated polymorphic `Comment` records?

Comment: Maybe [events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) are what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have previously created a service provider to listen for any Model deletes using Model Events as specified at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

However, this doesn't work if you're trying to listen to the `Model` class instead of a specific class such as `Notice`.

Instead, when you delete each model, a `eloquent.deleting` event is fired. I can then manually create a listener within the EventServiceProvider to listen for any model being deleted, and perform my checks accordingly, but without having the rely on the user overloading the `delete()` method and manually deleting the polymorphic relations.

**Answer**

If you want to delete polymorphic content automatically when you delete a model, make sure you either implement an interface or use a trait in the model.

For example, I want to delete all polymorphic comments when I delete the parent model record (If I delete a Notice record delete all polymorphic comments).

I created a `Commentable` trait which I use in any model (but you can just as easily use an empty interface on your model).

Then, in your `EventServiceProvider.php` alter the `boot()` method accordingly:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    /**
     * If you use a trait in your model:
     */
    $events->listen('eloquent.deleting*', function ($record) {
        if (in_array('App\Libraries\Traits\Commentable', class_uses($record))) {
            $record->deleteRelatedComments();
        }
    });


    /**
     * Or if you use an interface:
     */

    $events->listen('eloquent.deleting*', function ($record) {
        if ($record instanceof SomeInterface) {
            $record->deleteSomePolymorphicRelation();
        {
    });
}
```

---

**Use case:**

**Commentable Trait**

```
namespace App\Libraries\Traits;


trait Commentable 
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'content');
    }

    public function deleteRelatedComments()
    {
        $this->comments()->delete();
    }
}
```

**Commentable Model**

```
class Notice extends Model
{
    use Commentable;

    /** ... **/

    /**
     * NOTE: You do not need to overload the delete() method
     */
}
```

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    $events->listen('eloquent.deleting*', function ($record) {
        if (in_array('App\Libraries\Traits\Commentable', class_uses($record))) {
            $record->deleteRelatedComments();
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the developer creating a new content type that wants it to be commentable doesn't need to worry about creating the relations, managing the relation methods, or even deleting the polymorphic contents by overloading delete(). To make a model entirely commentable, they just need to use the `Commentable` trait and the framework handles everything.

This method can be used to automatically delete *any* polymorphic record, as long as the parent model implements some interface or uses a related trait.